# How do I iterate through a dictionary to find the highest value from a Key-Value pair using Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am working on a coding exercise and would like to write a code that can sift through the dictionary and return the name of the person with the highest score along with their score. This problem uses optionals and I want to ensure that I account for this within my solution? Here is the problem for example:

If you have a dictionary with 3 student names and their test scores, can you print the highest score?
e.g. if
studentsAndscores = ["Amy": 88, "James": 55, "Helen": 99]
Then your function should print 99.
But you don't know what the scores are, so your program has to handle all possibilities!
Hint: When you get the value out of a dictionary using a key, the value that comes out is an Optional!

Here is what I had so far after trying a dozen times. Although, I haven't been able to come close to a solution. I gotten a couple different errors that prevent me from understanding.

Here's my code:

````
given -> var studentsAndScores = ["Amy": Int(readLine()!)!, "James": Int(readLine()!)!, "Helen": Int(readLine()!)!]

given ->func highestScore(scores: [String: Int]) {
  
  //Write your code here. (My code below)
  for value in studentsAndScores.values {
  if studentsAndScores[value] == 99 {
      return("Key": String, Value: Int) 
  } else {
      return(false)
  }
  }
  
  
}```
````

Comment: Your code assumes that the highest score will always be 99. Based on the problem's wording, 99 is neither the highest possible score, nor is it guaranteed that there will even be a score of 99 in the dictionary. The problem asks you to find the highest score that's _present_ in the dictionary. It might help to analyze the steps in your own thought process if someone gives you a list of numbers to look at and asks you which one is the highest. Once you've identified each of those steps, it might be easier to code.

Comment: @mimo I'm looking to format my code in a way that takes in every case upon looking through the dictionaries. Do you know of any methods in Swift that could potentially help me solve this problem? Also could you tell me at all if there is anything I could place within my dictionary values for the if-statement? One of the biggest challenges for this problem is ensuring that it represent any given input. Otherwise this solution isn't even helpful at all!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. This approach assumes that a student can't have a negative test score. Inside the function, it choses 0 as the lowest value that a student can have. It then updates the maximum value each time that it reaches a value that is higher than the previously found maximum. because this uses '>' and not '>=' this will return the first person to found with the maximum score and the maximum score.

The approach is to loop through all of the key value pairs of the dictionary, in your example this was "Amy", "James", and "Helen", and then to check the score that each of them got. I named the key "student" and the value "scoreValue".

I used the values that you provided in your example instead of the "Int(readLine()!)!" that were provided, but that was just for easier demonstration. If those functions give you numbers correctly, then the dictionary iteration should do the trick.

Good luck with Swift!

```
var studentsAndScores = ["Amy": 88, "James": 55, "Helen": 99]


func highestScore(scores: [String: Int]) {
    var studentWithMaxScore: String = ""
    var maxValue: Int = -1 // This assumes that no one will score less than 0.
    
    for (student, scoreValue) in studentsAndScores {
        if scoreValue > maxValue {
            maxValue = scoreValue
            studentWithMaxScore = student
        }
    }
    
    //After you have tries all of the keys in the dictionary, your temporary variables should hold the name the student with the highest score and the highest score respectively.
    print("Student with highest score: \(studentWithMaxScore)")
    print("Score: \(maxValue)")
    
}

//This is calling the function on the dictionary provided. 
highestScore(scores: studentsAndScores)
```

Comment: With a `[String:Int]` dictionary the `guard let` expression is pointless because none of the values is `nil`. Why not `for (key, value) in studentsAndScores {`?

Comment: @DonovanSmith Great solution and well explained. Thank you, this doesn't exactly cover what I am trying to solve though. I'm not looking to use guard or continue. Also, could you tell me more about how including the variable maxValue helps the code find the greatest value when it's equal to 0?

Comment: @Jonathan Rodgers. The idea with choosing 0 as a starting value was that I was imagining that every student would have scored higher than nothing, which is not necessarily true. I will edit the solution to start from -1, which would work if the highest score was 0. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a `for` loop and check/set if the score is higher than the previous one; something like this:

```
var studentsAndScores = ["Amy": 88, "James": 55, "Helen": 99, "Dan":30]

var highestScore = 0
var studentWithHighestScore = ""

for (student, score) in studentsAndScores {
    if score > highestScore {
        highestScore = score
        studentWithHighestScore = student
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below:

```
var students = ["Amy": 88, "James": 55, "Helen": 99]

func highestScore(students: [String: Int]) -> Dictionary<String, Int>.Element? {
    return students.max(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
}

//Print the person with the highest score
if let topStudent = highestScore(students: students) {
    print("\(topStudent.key) has the highest score of \(topStudent.value)")
}
```

But I recommend you should revise your code as follows to more clearly:

```
struct Student {
    var name: String
    var score: Int
}

var students = [
    Student(name: "Amy", score: 88),
    Student(name: "James", score: 55),
    Student(name: "Helen", score: 99),
]

func highestScore(students: [Student]) -> Student? {
    return students.max(by: { $0.score < $1.score })
}

//Print the person with the highest score
if let topStudent = highestScore(students: students) {
    print("\(topStudent.name) has the highest score of \(topStudent.score)")
}
```